# Angular2 test Html

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I want to check the elements creates in html '*ngFor' with a Array in .ts , But I don't found documentation about it.

.ts :

```
steps: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

html :

```
<section class='mycontainer'>

  <article class="myArticle{{ steps.length }}">
    <div class='line'></div>
    <div *ngFor="let numberStep of steps;" class='circle'></div>
  </article>

</section>
```

I need check in **spect.ts** the elements create with ngFor

Comment: I don't know how do It

Comment: Here is the documentation for the same https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: I need check in spect.ts the elements create with ngFor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, here i look for all elements (div.circle) and check that count isn't equal to 0 to make sure that at least one is created. .queryAll return an array but you can use .query to get only one element

```
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(yourComponent);
 comp = fixture.componentInstance;

it('ngFor div should be created', () =>  {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      let ngForElement: DebugElement;
      ngForElement= fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('div.circle'));
      expect((ngForElement.length).not.toBe(0); // check that ngFor contain at least one element

 });
```

Comment: With   steps: Array<number> = []; The test is correct, but this test would not be correct because steps.length == 0 and the divs would be 0.

Comment: ngFor is a structural directive , yes if length == 0 the div element will not be created

Comment: you can mock a steps array and put some elements, and check that the div is created

Comment: I know It but in .spec. with code the "Fateh Mohamed " My array,length = 0 and test is succesfull and this is a error. do you understand
 me ?

Comment: In my component.ts Array.length = 0 , so , in spect.ts Never count(div)  > 1

Comment: En mi componente.ts   La longitud de mi Array  = 0 , por tanto, no podrán crearse divs, y tendría que fallar el spect.ts porque está puesto .not.toBe(0) Y ES 0 , porque Array.length = 0 .